# How do I configure the default email sender properties on a debian server?

Tags: linux, debian, exim

How can I configure the default mail sender properties on a debian server (with a mail transport agent of exim4, if it matters)?

**Background**

I'm running a server (debian 5, the mta is exim4) hosted by rackspace.  Rackspace mail uses outgoing sender address authentication, such that I can only send email from vetted "from" addresses.

Sending as, say, a local user results in a rejection:

```
  SMTP<< 550 5.1.0 <localuser@domainname.com>: 
Sender address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table
  SMTP<< 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
  SMTP>> QUIT
LOG: MAIN
  ** webadmin@domainname.com R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost: 
SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<webadmin@domainname.com>:
 host smtp.emailsrvr.com [xxxxxxx]: 550 5.1.0 <localuser@domainname.com>: 
Sender address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table
```

Problem is, I'm using a really simple app (logcheck, http://packages.debian.org/unstable/logcheck ) in an attempt to simply email out logs to myself. Logcheck doesn't have any built-in configuration for where the mail get sent from.

So whatever is the default is getting set as, by the system, I need to configure it to make sure it's a vetted address.  Where do I start?

Comment: Part of what ended up causing my problem is that only authorized users are allowed to send out via my rackspace smarthost, so I had to make sure that whoever the default send-out user was, the /etc/email-addresses alias mentioned below by coredump handled that fake user, and re-aliased it to a real user who the smarthost would truly accept.  In my case it was being sent out as www-data@mydomain.com because the www-data user was in control of the php scripts that were trying to send email.  Alias www-data to webadmin@mydomain.com and they started being delivered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `/etc/email-addresses` that associates outgoing email addresses with local user accounts (it's part of the default rewrite config of Debian's Exim). I think this is the better solution for your problem.

Also, during a `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` there's an option *Hide local mail name in outgoing name*, see if it can help you.

Comment: Using /etc/email-addresses definitely ended up solving my problem, gracias.